# How to modify section headings in APA6 document class?

Tags: sectioning, apa6

I am using the apa6 document class for a thesis and need changes for the section format:
\section: centered, normalfont (no bf), and control for line-spacing,
\subsection: instead of left aligned I need it centered, and control for line-spacing
\subsubsection: instead of in-line with paragraph I need it in the default format of \subsection: left aligned and bold

I tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}% <cmd>
  {\raggedright}% <search>
  {\centering}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}
\subsection{A section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[Reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497439/how-to-justify-section-headings-left-in-apa6-document-class)

I also tried the titelsec package, but it conflicts with the APA6 class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post your code in a compilable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `apa6` class file, `\subsection` definition doesn't contain the tag `\raggedright`, hence your tag doesn't work in a proper manner, please find the `\bfseries` tag in `\subsubsection` in `apa6`, then change it into `\centering\bfseries`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}% <cmd>
  {\bfseries}% <search>
  {\centering\bfseries}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}
\subsection{A section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!. Shortly after I posted I found two other solutions: Solution 1
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125537/how-to-modify-subsubsection-header-apa6-cls?rq=1
Solution 2
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195441/using-renewcommand-to-define-sections?rq=1

Comment: @togedo No issues, all our ultimate aim is the problem should resolve....

Comment: :-) Perhaps you can help me with this one: \makeatletter
\e@level@one@skip=1\baselineskip \@plus .2ex 
\e@level@two@skip=1\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex
\makeatother --- how can I define normalfont? for level one. That's all I need for getting 3 levels formatted then

Comment: What do you mean as normalfont? Hence the first level head came in normal font, i.e., Times, with bold series

Comment: well, not bold. I just noticed "\e@level@two@skip=1\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex" adds extra spaces between lines, how can I control that? Need just normal line spacing. So difficult all this, I am still a noob :-(

Comment: not in your patch Mady, in this one I 'd like normalfont "\e@level@two@skip=1\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex" THANKS!

Comment: Just remove the variable spaces, i.e., kept `1\baselineskip` only, just remove \@plus 0.2ex` and check...

Comment: Thanks again Mady, this works for me: https://pastebin.com/CPfJhygi

Comment: do you know how I can change in the APA6 class the format for paragraph from italic to normalfont? In the APA6 class manual (http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/apa6e/apa6e.pdf) p. 6 Line 70 to 73, I tried to remove or replace itshape and textit - didn't work at all.Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `paragraph` as fourth level head, if yes, try with the tags: `\patchcmd{\paragraph}% <cmd>
  {\bfseries\itshape}% <search>
  {\bfseries}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>`

Comment: that works!! Thank you again!! I wrote something like this, but used instead of \bfseries and \itshape textbf and textit which does not work.

Comment: @togedo If my suggestion works, can you accept the answer I gave you?

Comment: I sure can, new here, didn't know that I should - Thanks again for helping!!

Comment: Thanks for your understanding...